# Polymorphic functions as parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I have an ADT with two constructors; one that wraps a `Double` and one that wraps an `Integer`. I would like to create a function that takes a unary function on the `Num` typeclass and returns a function that applies that unary function to the contents of my ADT.

I've tried this:

```
data X = Y Integer
       | Z Double
wrap :: Num n => (n -> n) -> X -> X
wrap f (Y i) = Y $ f i
wrap f (Z i) = Z $ f i
```

But the compiler informs me that it can't match the type variable `n` to the type `Double` in the second definition of `wrap`:

```
test.hs:5:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘n’ with actual type ‘Double’
      ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          wrap :: forall n. Num n => (n -> n) -> X -> X
        at test.hs:3:9
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘i’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘f i’
      In the expression: Z $ f i
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: n -> n (bound at test.hs:5:6)
        wrap :: (n -> n) -> X -> X (bound at test.hs:4:1)
```

If I remove the second definition (so I only define `wrap` on the integer constructor `Y`), I get the same error, but on the first definition instead (and with `actual type 'Integer'` instead of double).

If instead I remove the type signature, the first definition causes it to infer the type `(Integer -> Integer) -> X -> X` for wrap, which (expectedly) causes the second definition to fail to type check.

This seems like such a simple problem that I must be missing something glaringly obvious. Thanks in advance for your help and patience!

Comment: `Num n => (n -> n)` means that your function will work with any function that takes transforms a concrete type to a concrete type so long as that type is an instance of Num. It does not mean it takes a function that can handle any instance of Num. What I am not sure is how to express that within the haskell typesystem.

Comment: Ah! That was exactly the clue I needed, thanks. Writing an answer now...

Comment: you need only change `wrap :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> X -> X`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @user1937198, I figured out that the implicit qualification of `n` was happening in the wrong scope; I was saying that I wanted to take a function that took any type that satisfied `Num` and mapped that type onto the same type, when what I wanted to say was I needed a function that took all types that satisfied `Num`. With `RankNTypes` the code becomes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
data X = Y Integer
       | Z Double
wrap :: (forall n. Num n => n -> n) -> X -> X
wrap f (Y i) = Y $ f i
wrap f (Z i) = Z $ f i
```

and all is good again. Thanks!