# Is there a way to DRY out the application of a polymorphic funtion to number of objects with different parameter types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

This is a simplified version of the problem I am facing (so functionally it makes no sense but this is a type problem).

```
module EGBase where
import           Prelude

newtype SomeData a b = SomeData String
```

---

```
module EGChild where
import           EGBase
import           Prelude

myData :: SomeData Int Int
myData = SomeData "Child"
```

---

```
module EGChild1 where
import           EGBase
import           Prelude

myData :: SomeData Int String
myData = SomeData "Child 1"
```

---

```
module EGMain where
import           EGBase
import           EGChild
import           EGChild1
import           Prelude

worker1 :: SomeData a b -> IO ()
worker1 _ = putStrLn "Hello from Worker 1"

worker2 :: SomeData a b -> IO ()
worker2 _ = putStrLn "Hello from Worker 2"

mergeThem :: [IO ()] -> IO ()
mergeThem = foldl (>>) (pure ())

main1 :: IO ()
main1 = mergeThem [
                worker1 EGChild.myData,
                worker1 EGChild1.myData
              ]

main2 :: IO ()
main2 = mergeThem [
                worker2 EGChild.myData,
                worker2 EGChild1.myData
              ]
```

The above compiles but in the actual application I will potentially have a lot of different workers I want to apply to a list of many modules (creating many versions of the application). I would like to abstact out rather than hard code the worker function.

As a first step I tried just pulling a hard coded worker out of the list but this didn't work because the list items were not the same type:

```
-- different types in list [SomeData Int Int, SomeData Int String]
main2Dry :: IO ()
main2Dry = mergeThem $ worker2 <$> [
                         EGChild.myData,
                         EGChild1.myData
                        ]
```

What I would really like is something like this but this would not work for the same reason as above:

```
mainShared :: (SomeData a b -> IO ()) -> IO ()
mainShared worker = mergeThem $ worker <$> [
                     EGChild.myData,
                     EGChild1.myData
                   ]
```

The following would be fine too but I guess the problem here is the concrete type of the worker function is inferred from the first element in the list meaning there are issues when the worker is applied to the second element:

```
mainShared :: (SomeData a b -> IO ()) -> IO ()
mainShared worker = mergeThem [
                       worker EGChild.myData,
                       worker EGChild1.myData
                     ]
--
-- does not compile
--
-- src\EGMain.hs:50:28-42: error:
--     * Couldn't match type `b' with `String'
--       `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
--         the type signature for:
--           mainShared :: forall a b. (SomeData a b -> IO ()) -> IO ()
--         at src\EGMain.hs:47:1-46
--       Expected type: SomeData a b
--         Actual type: SomeData Int String
--     * In the first argument of `worker', namely `EGChild1.myData'
--       In the expression: worker EGChild1.myData
--       In the first argument of `mergeThem', namely
--         `[worker EGChild.myData, worker EGChild1.myData]'
```

So is what I am trying to achieve possible in Haskell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymorphic functions as parameters in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403525/polymorphic-functions-as-parameters-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible in standard Haskell, but there are several extensions that would let you do this, including GADTs and RankNTypes.

A workaround that might work in your simplified example but perhaps not in your real code is to just erase the dummy type parameters:

```
erase :: SomeData a b -> SomeData () ()
erase (SomeData x) = SomeData x

mainShared :: (SomeData () () -> IO ()) -> IO ()
mainShared worker = mergeThem $ map worker [
                       erase EGChild.myData,
                       erase EGChild1.myData
                     ]
```

Comment: FTR, most Haskellers wouldn't understand “standard Haskell” so much as plain Haskell2010 but as “GHC 7.10~~8.2”. GADTs are a long-established part of this. However, I don't think they would really address the problem better than a Haskell98 solution.

Comment: Solution based on the `RankNTypes` suggestion in this answer below

Answer (score 0):

Using RankNTypes as suggested by Jonas Duregård worked:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

worker1 :: forall a b. SomeData a b -> IO ()
worker1 _ = putStrLn "Hello from Worker 1"

worker2 :: forall a b. SomeData a b -> IO ()
worker2 _ = putStrLn "Hello from Worker 2"

mergeThem :: [IO ()] -> IO ()
mergeThem = foldl (>>) (pure ())

mainShared :: (forall a b. SomeData a b -> IO ()) -> IO ()
mainShared worker = mergeThem [
                    worker EGChild.myData,
                    worker EGChild1.myData
                    ]

demo1 = mainShared worker1
-- > Hello from Worker 1
-- > Hello from Worker 1

demo2 = mainShared worker2
-- > Hello from Worker 2
-- > Hello from Worker 2
```

I found this reference on RankNTypes useful https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html.